# Modifying the statistical distribution of some property for a set of objects

Tags: python, statistics, distribution

I have a synthetic population of N people whose age is a multiple of 10 (from 0 to 100 years). The vector `A` of the people ages is the input of my system. Obviously, the values of vector `A` (of size N) can be 0,10,20...100

The age distribution looks like:
[image]
I want now to have the age **not being a multiple of 10** in order to have a continuous distribution in my synthetic population. I can afford **to change the age of some people** in order to have a smooth distribution looking like this:
[image]

However, I have not yet found a practical way to perform this age modification starting from `A`.

**My question is**: how to compute the modified "age vector" `A'` from `A` with `A'` having values for every integer value in [0,100] ? Ideally, I'm looking for a Python solution but any theoretical answer would help to implement a Python solution.

Comment: add a random int n times to each age group? (where your random int goes from 0 to 9 and follows a normal distribution?)

Comment: @E.Serra, I indeed tried something like this but with poor results because the probability within an age group is not the same and eventually I got some "step" effects. In the example for the age group "60", I should generate more people at age 69 than for age 62 since the next age group "70" is bigger than the group "60". In fact, I suspect that it is necessary in some case to change the group for some people in order to respect the initial distribution per decade. But I don't know yet how to do this.

Comment: do you need it to be random? you can just add 1/10 of next age total - this age total and that would give you a 'line' between each age group, if you want it to be random, you can also adddd a random amount to those numbers and that should be good enough]

Comment: if I understand, it would mean that the total number of people is also changed but I need to keep the same total number N of people (which is not clear in my question). In other words, the vector A' must have the same size as the vector A